# How to redirect to 2 different app in django, base on the user group from single login url

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-auth-models

I have the following scenario:

My project has two different Django apps, Dashboard and FrontView, with different user groups.
Current login urls are as below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/login
http://127.0.0.1:8000/front/login
```

However, I have a requirement to have a single login url based on the user redirect to the correct app. EG:

URL for logging in

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`

Once logged in, it should redirect the user to two different apps base on the user group.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/front/
```

How to achieve  this in Django project

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you define a custom login view? What mechanism currently logs in users?

Comment: have not really understood the question. do you have two different authentication logics for dashboard and front apps?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, a super user considered a user in a way. In order to determine which address your user should go to, you should check whether your user is a superuser or not. If he is a super user, you can send it to the dashboard, otherwise you can send it to the front.
you can use `request.user.is_superuser` to find that current user is super user or not if he is super user you send it to dashboard (whit redirect method) and if its not you can send it to front.

i hope this explanation helps you.